# Meta tag wordpress

Tags: wordpress, html-meta-tag

Desenvolvi um site em wordpress para administração de imoveis para alugar casas e apartamentos na praia, e estou com dúvidas de como posso adicionar meta tags para otimizar as buscas no google, como posso resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do Wordpress aqui: https://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

> Para adicionar meta tags ao seu site, simplesmente as adicione ao arquivo header.php do seu arquivo de template do seu tema Wordpress, especificamente na seção HEAD perto dos links das stylesheets (folhas de estilo CSS).

Traduzi de forma livre mas a ideia é bem simples.